# How to count agents with specific characteristic in block?

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent population "agent" that enters my process, they need to wait in a queue block before being processed. My agents have a paramenter called "model", I can have up to 6 different models being produced in my production line. At the end of the day, I need to calculate how many agents of each model are in my queue. Is there an easy way to calculate this?

I have tried already "queue.size(agent.model == "model") but it doesn't seam to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this code to count for example how many agents are model equals to 3, assuming that your model is defined by a number:

```
count(queue,q->q.model==3)
```

if your model value is something else (string, class, option list, etc)

```
count(queue,q->q.model.equals(MODEL_VALUE))
```

Comment: I tried myself and it works perfectly fine... So you will need to give more information to get an answer... good luck

Comment: Thank you! I will try again!!